# When to use NSDictionary & NSArray during HTTP requests and JSON parsing?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a question regarding when to use NSDictionary & when to use NSArray while you are making a HTTP request and getting JSON data back.

For example if the JSON coming back is an **array of objects** like below:

```
   [
      {object1},
      {object2},
      .........
   ]
```

I have the following line in my code:

```
 if let books:Array<AnyObject> = json[""] as? Array<AnyObject> {
 }
```

Its giving an error:

> Array< anyObject >? is not convertible to Array< anyObject >

Parsing:

```
var json:NSMutableArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSMutableArray
            if (jsonError != nil) {
                println("Error parsing json: \(jsonError)")
            }
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong.

**UPDATE:**

Currently I have the following code:

```
class func getBooks(completion: (result:Array<BookSummary>)->()) {

    var bookArray = [BookSummary]()
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://something.herokuapp.com/user/all")
    if let tempUrl:NSURL = url {
        let urlReq = NSURLRequest(URL: tempUrl)
        let queue = NSOperationQueue()
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlReq, queue: queue, completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println("API error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
            var jsonError:NSError?
            var newBook = BookSummary(id: "", title: "", fullname: "", thumbnail: "")
            if let arr = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? [AnyObject] {
                for a in arr {
                    //println(a)
                    //println( arr[0])
                     println( arr[0])
                }
            }
```

By doing `println(arr[0])` I am getting the object at the first index.

But if I try `println(arr[0].fullname)` it comes up with an error:

> any object does not have a member named fullname

Comment: @Arbitur Thank you for the reply. What is the right approach then. I have an API which sends back JSON. but I can't seem to parse it. Are there any specific steps involved in HTTP requests and parsing JSON within swift

Comment: How are you making the request?

Comment: My bad, a json actually can start as an array. How are you parsing it? Are you using NSJSONSerialization ?

Comment: @Arbitur Thank you for the reply. Yes I am using NSJSONSerialization. Please see the edited post above. All I want to do is make a HTTP request, get JSON data back, parse it and use it as I see fit. I have been stuck on this for days. Its very easy to do this in javascript. because there are specific steps to follow but I am extremely confused with swift as I don't see any specific steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the standard `NSJSONSerialization` to parse from JSON string you use the JSONObjectWithData() class function.

This returns AnyObject? and can be parsed to either Dictionary or Array.

So if the JSON string starts with "[" its parseable to an Array:

```
if let arr = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? [AnyObject] { 
     for a in arr {
         println(a)
     }

     // Other options to access the values
     println( arr[0] )
     println( arr.first )
}
```

And if it starts with a "{" its parseable to a Dictionary:

```
if let dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String:AnyObject] { 
     for (key, value) in dict {
         println("\(key) = \(value)")
     }

     // Other options to access the values
     println( dict["someKey"] )
     println( dict[dict.keys[0]] )
     println( dict[dict.keys.first] )
}
```

> In Swift I recommend you dont use NSDictionary and NSArray and use Swifts own Dictionary and Array instead. Mostly because Swift is so type safe and you can control the types on a Swift Dictionary and Array and not the old NS stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much. this cleared a lot of things for me. By using your code I am getting the entire JSON being logged on the console. But how do I get a specific value. For example each object in the array has a "fullname" property. I tried this "println(a.fullname) " but that did not work. whats the right way of parsing the JSON data further. So I can retrieve specific values.  Again Thank you so much

Comment: If it is parsed into a Dictionary you get the values with a key. dict["fullname"] this will return AnyObject? or whatever you casted it to.

Comment: Keep in mind that a JSON object in Javascript is a real OBJECT therefore you can just do the .property and get a value. But in most other languages Swift included JSON object is not a real OBJECT its just a formatted string and has to be parsed into something the language can work with.

Comment: Which in this case a Dictionary. And the Dictionary's values is accessible with a key, usually a string but can be something else too like an Int. The syntax looks like this: dict[key] and returns a value.

Comment: As my JSON starts with "[" I have parsed it to an array. As you have done in the answer above. Do need I now need parse into a dictionary so swift can understand it?

Comment: If the elements inside that Array are objects a.k.a Dictionary you have to parse the elements to Dictionary. while parsing you can cast it to [[String:AnyObject]] which will create an Array of Dictionaries.

Comment: See my update, I show you the ways to access the values for each type.

Comment: Again thank you so much for all the help. You are the first person to help and actually make sense. Thank you. I have added a an update on my post if you could have a look. I am getting an error.

Comment: After your update: As I said you're not in Javascript now, you are working with Swift stuff. If your JSON array only contains objects (Dictionaries in Swift) you can cast it in the if let to [[String:AnyObject]]. Then when you access the arrays elements you will get a Dictionary. Dictionaries uses keys to access its values.

Comment: Apologies, I did not have access to the internet over the weekend. And yes it does work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

To parse this json data from CDiscount API which contains Products/Price/Name :

```
{
        "ItemCount": "34",
        "PageCount": "7",
        "PageNumber": "0",
        "Products": [
        {
        "AssociatedProducts": null,
        "BestOffer": {
            "Condition": "New",
            "Id": "MD531NFA",
            "IsAvailable": true,
            "PriceDetails": {
                    "Discount": null,
                    "ReferencePrice": "249.00",
                    "Saving": {
                        "Type": "Amount",
                        "Value": "17.0"
                        }
                },
            "ProductURL": "http://www.cdiscount.com/opa.aspx/?trackingid=T1mQnsY6DVL2nQMfDBv95HJiDedNp6Iusby9wMMBIWJ8xCUTe2ax25EOmRJ_4IkI&action=product&id=MD531NFA",
            "SalePrice": "231.98",
            "Seller": {
                "Id": "0",
                "Name": "Cdiscount"
                },
            "Shippings": null,
            "Sizes": null
            },
        "Brand": "APPLE",
        "Description": "Tablette tactile avec écran 7,9\" capacitif - Processeur Apple A5 bicoeur - Stockage 16Go - WiFi 802.11 b/g/n - Camera avant 1,2Mpixels - Caméra arrière 5Mpixels - Connecteur Lightning reversible - Jusqu’à 10h d'autonomie - IOS 6 - Garantie 1 an",
        "Ean": null,
        "Id": "MD531NFA",
        "Images": null,
        "MainImageUrl": "http://i2.cdscdn.com/pdt2/N/F/A/1/300x300/MD531NFA.jpg",
        "Name": "Apple iPad mini Wi-Fi 16 Go blanc & argent",
        "Offers": null,
        "OffersCount": "10",
        "Rating": "4.69"
        }
        ]
    }
```

From this data, I wanted to print the product name and its price.
So I should first parse in the Json object as dictionary in search for 'Products' key, and the results as an AnyObject.

```
let products: AnyObject = jsonDict["Products"]
```

Then loop through all products and for each one loop over the dictionary keys

```
for aProduct in products as! NSArray{

        for aKey in (aProduct as! NSDictionary).allKeys{
```

Based on the json data model, it's enough to print the product name :

```
if aKey as! String == "Name"{
                    if let name: AnyObject = aProduct["Name"]{
                        println("Product : \(name) ->")
                    }
                }
```

But I need to go deeper in the data tree to print the price as it is stored in another dictionary of dictionary.

```
if aKey as! String == "BestOffer"{
                if let offers: AnyObject = aProduct["BestOffer"]{
                    for offerDetail in (offers as! NSDictionary).allKeys{
                        if offerDetail as! String == "SalePrice"{
                            if let price: AnyObject = offers["SalePrice"]{
                                println("|--> Price: \(price)")
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

So to resume :

```
// Get data in a swift Dictionary
let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as? [String: AnyObject]


// Begin navigate through the dictionary (here through 'Products')
if let products: AnyObject = jsonDict["Products"]{
        // Get product data through loop in a NSArray
        for aProduct in products as! NSArray{
            // Loop over keys in one product as NSDictionary
            for aKey in (aProduct as! NSDictionary).allKeys{
                // test key value
                if aKey as! String == "Name"{
                    // if exists, print product name
                    if let name: AnyObject = aProduct["Name"]{
                        println("Product : \(name) ->")
                    }
                }
                // another test key value
                if aKey as! String == "BestOffer"{
                    // same as before to get deeper in the json tree structure
                    if let offers: AnyObject = aProduct["BestOffer"]{
                        for offerDetail in (offers as! NSDictionary).allKeys{
                            if offerDetail as! String == "SalePrice"{
                                if let price: AnyObject = offers["SalePrice"]{
                                    println("|--> Price: \(price)")
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: Glad to have helped !

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comment, i think you want to look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Simple example:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    // here is where you import the JSON data from responseObject

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

`NSDictionary` is unsorted, but associative where as `NSArray` is sorted but index only. One way is to obtain all the keys of the `JSON` data into an `NSArray` so the order of the data structure is maintained, then import the data into `NSDictionary`. Then you can use the value from the keys array to reference the `NSDictionary`

**The example is for Objective-C, however hopefully it will still be relevant**